# How to reuse an entire mmenu instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I have this mmenu instance where I dynamically add content from ajax just as described on the plugin's page.

Now I not only want to add sublevels dynamically, I want to throw away all levels and add a new first level to the existing mmenu instance.

I've tried calling `API.initPanels($("#mm-0"))`, I've tried removing all classes from DOM elements that were added by mmenu before initializing the mmenu plugin again but it won't render a proper menu. The UL and LIs I add remain untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, here's how:

```
API.closeAllPanels();
var mmenuActual = API.getInstance();
var $panels = mmenuActual.$pnls.children();
var $updateContainer = $panels.first().find(".mm-listview");

$updateContainer.replaceWith(newContent);
$panels.not(":first").remove();
API.initPanels($panels);
```

First we need to close all panels to set **mmenu** back to its' initial state where only the top level is visible.

Next, we need to get hold of all panels and the `.mm-listview` of the first panel, because that's where **mmenu** renders the first level from.

Then we update the first level's source with our new content. It doesn't matter if you update the `innerHTML` of that element or swap it like I did.

The rest of the panels is now obsolete, we throw them all away.

Finally, we tell **mmenu** to initialize all panels